# Facebook 'Like' Count on website not matching 'Like' Count on post of Facebook page Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We have a website where we have article pages, each with a Facebook like button on them and associated with that articles URL (url encoded). So for instance on some article with url `http://www.site.com/article/my-big-article` the Facebook Like code looks like:

```
 <fb:like class=" fb_edge_widget_with_comment fb_iframe_widget" action="like" width="50" layout="button_count" send="true" href="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.site.com%2Farticle%2Fmy-big-article"> ...etc
```

Our problem is when we make a post to our companies Facebook page attaching the url of the article (i.e. "http://www.site.com/article/my-big-article") the number of likes doesn't match. This is a fairly recent problem.

Any ideas as to how to "fix" this so that our websites article page like button will map to that of the post being made to our Facebook wall? (Both intended to map to the same URL).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I do recall correctly, when I last used a like button, I ran into similar issues. I believe we found in the documentation that Facebook's like number that it returns in some cases also includes statuses and comments that mention the URL, leading to a discrepancy in the numbers.  We solved this by altering the FQL we were using.  Hopefully this can get you on the right track! (Sorry I can't be more specific about the like button, we rolled our own instead of using Facebook's supplied one)